# Why ogr2ogr -lco OVERWRITE doesn't work on PostgreSQL public schemas?

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, import

I've created a `bash` script with `ogr2ogr` as the following:

```bsh
PARAMS=(
    -f "PostgreSQL"
    PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=my_database"
    -nlt GEOMETRY
    -lco SCHEMA="my_schema"
    -lco overwrite=yes
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry
    -nln "layer_name"
    "input.geojson"
)
ogr2ogr "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

It works perfectly fine for importing a table called `layer_name` inside `my_schema` on`my_database`, it imports the data and if I run this command again it overwrites the table.

Well, that works because I'm using a `schema` other than the `public`, if I try to execute this same command on the `public` schema as following:

```bsh
PARAMS=(
    -f "PostgreSQL"
    PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=my_database"
    -nlt GEOMETRY
    -lco overwrite=yes
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry
    -nln "layer_name"
    "input.geojson"
)
ogr2ogr "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Even though it works for importing the data, if I run `ogr2ogr` with these parameters again I receive the warning:

```
Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is being appended to.
```

It completely ignores the `-lco overwrite=yes` parameter and it's different from my first sample, which overwrites the table. This second `ogr2ogr` command will append the data on the table each time I run this command. Why does that happen only on the `public` schema? Is there any extra parameter that I need to use with `overwrite` on the public schema to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue with latest GDAL `GDAL 3.5.0dev, released 2022/99/99`.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=password" -nlt geometry -lco geometry_name=geometry -nln overwritetest test.shp -lco overwrite=yes
Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is
         being appended to.
```

A workaround is to use the `-overwrite` switch of ogr2ogr instead

> -**overwrite**
>
> Delete the output layer and recreate it empty

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=password" -nlt geometry -lco geometry_name=geometry -nln overwritetest test.shp -overwrite
```

I think that you have found a bug and you have enough details to go to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues and make a bug report.

**EDIT**
It seems that you still cannot edit your script to use the -overwrite option of ogr2ogr everywhere:

> **SCHEMA**: Set name of schema for new table. Using the same layer name in
> different schemas is supported, but not in the public schema and
> others. Note that using the -overwrite option of ogr2ogr and -lco
> SCHEMA= option at the same time will not work, as the ogr2ogr utility
> will not understand that the existing layer must be destroyed in the
> specified schema. Use the -nln option of ogr2ogr instead, or better
> the active_schema connection string.

Comment: Thanks! I got to the conclusion that with `-overwrite` it works on the public schema but it doesn't work on other ones. The `-lco overwrite` is the other way around, it works with schemas that are not public but with the public one it doesn't work. And if by any chance I have a table with the same name in the public and different schemas I'll get an error too.

Comment: Also, in my case I'm using GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01.